# programically call multiple shortcodes in multiple pages

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have two shortcodes like below:

```
function callback_func1($atts){
ob_start();
include(locate_template('name_of_php_file.php'));
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('name_of_php_file','callback_func1');

function callback_func2($atts){
ob_start();
include(locate_template('name_of_another_php_file.php'));
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('name_of_another_php_file','callback_func2');
```

Now I have a blog page widget-shortcode which has fields like `[name_of_another_php_file title="Style" sub-title="need?"]` from where I want to render `title` and `subtitle` to my main `home.php` file.

How to do it??

I tried the below code in my home.php but it does not work.

```
<h2 class="main-title thx"><?php echo sanitize_text_field($atts['title']) ?></h2>

<p class="sub-title drb"><?php echo sanitize_text_field($atts['sub-title']) ?></p>
```

Comment: Do the <h2> and the <p> show up at all?

Comment: Im just trying a suggestion: change your "sub-title" to "subtitle" or "sub_title" because shortcode atts may have some limitation with that. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: @maggiathor yes